# How to add a input from form too array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to practice forms in react, I am able to successfully display the result onClick, however I want to store them in array so I can map over them and store them in a list. I have tried doing the spread operator but that only returns 1 value. can anyone help? Here is the code in a sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-tree-p49rw?file=/src/App.jshttps://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-cdn-je05d

Comment: In what file is the spread operator - I couldn't find it. In any case, could you perhaps also quote the relevant section in your code in addition to linking to the sandbox (which is a great thing to do, don't get me wrong ;) ).

Comment: SetResult is using the spread operator, unless that is wrong? haha. But either way I would love to know how to push the value into an array :) and sure!

Comment: Where can I see "SetResult"? All I see in the sandbox is what seems to be a react template...

Comment: It is the input value if you click on the submit form. Its also logged to the console..

Comment: This is what I see: https://imgur.com/a/xl4Pnq2 . Unless I'm having issues, it is possible you may have not saved / published your changes...

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-tree-p49rw?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Try that link. I think it didn't save, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

You need to pass to setResults a new array, perform the spread on the "result" parameter and then add the input value after that:

```js
    setResult([...result, input]);
```

## In more detail:

So let me go over the code to explain the problem.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Spread operator??
    setResult(...input, input);
    console.log(input);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}></input>
        <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          submit
        </button>
      </form>
      <h2>{result}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

From what I understand you were trying to create an input (whose value is stored int he "input" state) that submits the data you type in it into an array (the "result" array).

You defined the behaviour of the input correctly:

`<input type="text" onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}></input>`

Whenever the user types something into the input, the value (a string) is stored into the input state via set state, which, as a useState hook, takes 1 argument and updates the state to hold it.

Now note that result is also a useState hook, meaning that setResult behaves exactly the same - it expects 1 argument and stores that value into the state.

Here are the problems in your code:

1. You spread the wrong value - ...input will spread the string "input"'s characters as separate values (i.e. `[..."test"]` will give you ```["t", "e", "s", "t"].
2. Rather than spreading values into a new array, you spread the values as arguments to setResults.

As a result, every time you submitted the form, you passed the first letter of your input to setResults, changing it from an array to a string holding the first character of the input:
[image: Typing "test" in the input results in the character "t" appearing under the input]